# The security token included in the request is expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a script that pulls a lot of metrics from Cloudwatch for our own internal reports.

The script iterates all of the EC2 instances in a specific region and  ask for 5 cloudwatch metrics (all the statistics available) for the past 2 weeks (each time 5 days back in 5 minutes interval which is exactly the 1440 quota). I'm using an assumed session:

```
session = Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region_name=regionName)
sts = session.client('sts')
response = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn=arn, # External role arn
    RoleSessionName='role-name',
    ExternalId='<some-id-here>',
)
tempAccessKeyId = response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
tempSecretAccessKey = response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
tempSessionToken = response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
assumedSession = Session(
    aws_access_key_id=tempAccessKeyId,
    aws_secret_access_key=tempSecretAccessKey,
    aws_session_token=tempSessionToken,
    region_name=regionName)
```

While running the script I got this exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the GetMetricStatistics operation: The security token included in the request is expired
```

Is there a way to make sure the token doesn't expire while running the script? I'm using boto3.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The assume_role method you are using returns **temporary** security credentials. The following is taken from the [official documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role):

> The temporary security credentials are valid for the duration that you specified when calling AssumeRole , which can be from 900 seconds (15 minutes) to 3600 seconds (1 hour). The default is 1 hour.

Since you are not using the `DurationSeconds` keyword argument, the returned credentials are valid for the default 1 hour. You must make sure to get new credentials in order to make requests after 1 hour. See the following from the [Temporary Security Credentials official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html):

> When (or even before) the temporary security credentials expire, the user can request new credentials, as long as the user requesting them still has permissions to do so.

Answer (score 65):

In my case the issue was that, I had credentials in my `.aws/configure` and was trying to configure from that but what I didn't realize is I had another pair of credentials `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` set in environmental variables.

you can do this ( which will remove credentials from environment ).

```
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Now you will have only one set of access keys i.e in `.aws/configure` and I was able to make connection sucessfully.

```
aws configure
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

if you are using profile other than default, use `--profile` flag in the above command.

Comment: For me it was an override.tf file that had been created which had the incorrect profile explicitly set in there, similar issue.

Answer (score 7):

I also face this error and even I checked my `.aws/credential` file. It contains credentials but still I will recommend following step:

before doing anything, first thing you must do run following command

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

if you have more than one profile in aws credential then use this one

you can check your profile in following file `.aws/credential`. If you have only `[default]` then no need to mention profile

```
aws --profile NAME_OF_YOUR_PROFILE  sts get-caller-identity
```

Now the question is that above command will solve the problem?

No, But at least it will let you know that your credential are correct or not. I was facing same error and when I run above command it give me following error

`An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`

So at least I find out that I was using wrong credential. I just replace credential and my problem get solved.

Comment: When using granted, it worked for me by updating the credentials file with `assume <profile> --ex`

Answer (score 2):

Instance time sync issue can also cause this which blocks IAM token refresh, I had tried all the solutions but nothing worked and finally found that its the time difference with instance and AWS services. Installing chrony can help in automatic time sync.

Answer (score 1):

I found [AWS Premium Support answer](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/security-token-expired/) for the issue very concise and relevant

Also important to note that error sometimes comes up when server time is drifted from the correct time (10-15 minutes will cause the error)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while trying to refresh token using:
`aws sts get-session-token`
I think the reasons for this error is because of the reasons shared in answers above but for me to solve it simply I requested a new access key from AWS IAM security credentials tab. When I used this new key and removed the session_token from the config file then I was finally able to run the get-sessions-token command.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Azure AD to login to AWS simply re-run [aws-azure-login](https://github.com/aws-azure-login/aws-azure-login) command and it will refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to re login through the terminal to your AWS account.

Comment: it would be a good answer if you add the example of how to login