# ExpiredTokenException: Gitlab runner on AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-ecs, gitlab-ci-runner, aws-fargate

I have set up a GitLab runner on AWS fargate. It works perfectly fine one time and after some time it throws `ExpiredTokenException` while running jobs.

```
ERRO[2022-04-07T04:04:31Z] Application execution failed                  PID=16444 error="starting new Fargate task: running new task on Fargate: error starting AWS Fargate Task: ExpiredTokenException: The security token included in the request is expired\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: xxxxxxxxxx"
```

I have read troubleshoot docs from Gitlab and AWS but there is no related information about `ExpiredTokenException`. The links are:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/#troubleshooting
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html

I would appreciate any lead to this problem.

Comment: I have found a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685729/the-security-token-included-in-the-request-is-expired but not sure whether it works or not.

Comment: In my case, while building AWS resources using CDK and for that, I have created a role and assigned that role to the task definition. The problem was the session of that role is 1 hour by default so within that hour it works normally but after the session expires it throws `ExpiredTokenException`. For more details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/Role.html